# php - can someone help me make a sql sort to get listing between 2 price values?

Tags: php, sql

i need to sort this table to show prices between 2 values that are set with text boxes but ive tryed loads of veriations but it just wont work
here is the form for the text box and what i think the query should be(from index2.php):

```
<form action ="index2.php" method="post">
                        Games priced<input action="index2.php" method="post" type="text" name="min">
                        Between<input action="index2.php" method="post" type="text" name="max">
                        <input type="submit" value="Sort">

                        <?php

                        $query = "SELECT * FROM CSGames WHERE price <=min AND >=max ";
                        $result = pg_query("SELECT * FROM CSGames WHERE price <=min AND >=max ");

                        ?>
```

and this is the sql database im useing

```
<?php
$con = pg_connect("bla bla");
    if (!$con)
        {
    die('Could not connect: ' . pg_error());
        }
    $result = pg_query("SELECT * FROM CSGames");
    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Platform</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Select</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)){
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['2'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['3'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['4'] . "</td>";
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="games[]" value="' . $row['1'] . '|||' . $row['2'] . '|||'. $row['3'] . '|||' . $row['4'] . '"/></td>';

    echo"</tr>";      
        }
    echo"</table>";

pg_close($con);
```

?>

i think its just the query thats wrong but im not sure 
if it helps this is the page im working on 
http://users.aber.ac.uk/edd14/cs25010/index.php

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, a between clause just for these situations:

```
SELECT * FROM `CSGames`
WHERE `price` BETWEEN min AND max;
```

Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Replace min and max with your *sanitized* $_POST variables from your form.

Comment: sorry, its throwing:     Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: column "min" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM CSGames WHERE price BETWEEN min AND max; ^ in /ceri/homes1/e/edd14/public_html/cs25010/index2.php on line 59

Comment: You need to replace min and max with your variables from your input. I mentioned that in the answer... `$query = "SELECT * FROM `CSGames` WHERE `price` BETWEEN {$_POST['min']} AND {$_POST['max']}";`

Comment: cant copy this in in one go

Comment: i think im being really stupid but this is what ive done so far:

    <form action ="index2.php" method="post">
       Games priced<input action="index2.php" method="post" type="text" name="minimum">
       Between<input action="index2.php" method="post" type="text" name="maximim">
       <input type="submit" value="Sort">
       
       <?php  
       $min= minimum;
       $max= maximum;
       if (isset($_POST['games'])) { 
        echo $_POST['min'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['games'])) { 
        echo $_POST['max'];
        }

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM CSGames` WHERE price BETWEEN {$_POST['minimum']} AND {$_POST['maximum']}";
       $result = pg_query("SELECT * FROM CSGames WHERE price BETWEEN {$_POST['minimum']} AND {$_POST['maximum']}");
       ?>
       </form>

Answer (score 1):

```
     $query = "SELECT * FROM CSGames WHERE price >=min AND price <=max ";
     $result = pg_query("SELECT * FROM CSGames WHERE price >=min AND price <=max ");
```

Comment: it keeps throwing : Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: No PostgreSQL link opened yet in /ceri/homes1/e/edd14/public_html/cs25010/index2.php on line 61

Comment: that sounds like you haven't established a connection to your database yet and has nothing to do with the query. http://php.net/manual/de/function.pg-pconnect.php